# How to draw at the centre of a subview

Tags: ios, swift3, bounds

I want to draw an arrow at the center of a SubView which is created by

```
    {let arrowView = ArrowView()
    arrowView.frame = CGRect(x: selectButton.frame.minX, y: selectButton.frame.maxY, width: selectButton.frame.width, height: processButton.frame.minY - selectButton.frame.maxY)
    arrowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    arrowView.viewWithTag(100)
    view.addSubview(arrowView)
    } //these codes are in the view controller
```

To draw the arrow in the subview I use the

```
    let arrowPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPathWithArrowFromPoint(startPoint: startPoint, endPoint: endPoint, tailWidth: 4, headWidth: 8, headLength: 6)
// the error occurs here

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let fillColor = UIColor.white
    fillColor.setFill()

    arrowPath.lineWidth = 1.0
    let strokeColor = UIColor.blue
    strokeColor.setStroke()

    arrowPath.stroke()
    arrowPath.fill()
 //these codes are in the subclass of UIView
```

Since I want to draw the arrow at the center of the subview,
I define the startPoint and the endPoint as

```
    private var startPoint: CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY)
}
private var endPoint: CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY)
} 
//try to find the point at the centre of Subview
```

However, this code does not compile and the error says:

**Cannot use instance member 'startPoint' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available**

Edit:
I would like to know how the get the bounds of a subview created by code.
I try the "bounds" variable but get the above error.

Comment: Why make us guess where the error occurs? Did you search the error and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40711615/1971013) and other clues?

Answer (score 1):

```
arrowPath.center = CGPoint(x:arrowView.frame.size.width/2, y: arrowView.frame.size.height/2)

arrowView.addSubview(arrowPath)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I am still confused about your answer.  Should I add your code to the View Class or the View Controller Class? I use the bezier path function to draw on the subview. I want to draw in the center of the Subview but I can not use the bounds property of the subview which gives me the above error.

Comment: Hello, you could use it on the view controller. Please try it and do tell me